# jquery multiselect reload

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I add or remove options in [JQuery UI Multiselect](http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) ? I am initializing the multiselect on page load and I need to remove existing values and add new values based on another selection. I am initializing the multiselect on page load using:

```
$("#multipleselectboxId").multiselect();
```

After that, I am adding values to the multiple drop down using jQuery `append()` and `remove()` methods which are working fine with original dropdown but in the multiselect are not getting reflected.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the solution for this, first destroy the multiselect and reInitialize it, Thanks for @ Brandon Joyce,

solutions for this is

```
$("#multipleselectboxId").append(toAppend);
$("#multipleselectboxId").remove(toRemove);

$("#multipleselectboxId").multiselect('destroy');
$("#multipleselectboxId").multiselect();
```

Comment: This answer is confusing to me. Can you explain the first two lines of your solution and how they relate to the reload?

Comment: Excuse me,are you sure you shouldnt accept @Brandon Joyce answer as the first comming true answer?!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!! Using 'destroy' before initializing the multiselect sorted out my issue! Thanks!

Comment: This is the answer I was searching for

Answer (score 31):

For that one you could just destroy and reinitialize after changing...

```
$("#multipleselectboxId").append(toAppend).multiselect("destroy").multiselect();
```

There's also another plugin with a refresh function: [EricHynds's Multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#refresh)

```
$("#multipleselectboxId").append(toAppend).multiselect("refresh");
```

Comment: no. I have tried, It is not working and the plugin you have mentioned is not same as i ma using, I am using from this link  http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_original/

Comment: Ah, well, if all else fails, can you destroy it and reinitialize?  It looks like it's using the widget factory so this should be possible.

Comment: I am getting exception `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).multiselect is not a function..`
For some reason I need to use upper case and then it works, e.g. `$("#multipleselectboxId").multiSelect();`
I am using default jQuery UI multiselects.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to rebuild multiselect by `.multiselect("destroy")` and `.multiselect()`, but it wasnt working, so finally I find this solution worked for me.

```
$.each(jsonArray, function(i, val) {
    $('#frmarticles-f_category_id').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+val+'</option>').multiselect('rebuild');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I just wanted to replace all previous content of multiselect with new.

This worked for me:

```
$('#multiselect_id').html(newHtml);
$('#multiselect_id').multiselect('refresh');
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you this helped. I was using multiselect UI widget and this is what worked

```
jQuery("select[title='" + FieldNameTitleText + "']").append( "<option value='" + OptionValue+ "'>" + OptionText + "</option>" ).multiselect("refresh");
```

Comment: Chained or not after "append()" using "refresh" works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did:; it may be more than necessary, but it worked for me.

Original "select" code that requires modification:

```
<select id="MySelect" name="selection">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

I rebuild the option list in PHP, send it to the JavaScript via JSON, and construct/store the new list in a variable. E.g.:

```
// this is similar to if we got it from PHP
var newList = '<option value="A">Alpha</option>
<option value="B">Beta</option>
<option value="C">Gamma</option>';
```

Now, to switch this around in the jQuery UI Multiselect widget:

```
$('#MySelect').html(''); // clear out old list
$('#MySelect').multiselect('destroy');  // tell widget to clear itself
$('#MySelect').html(newList); // add in the new list
$('#MySelect').multiselect(); // re-initialize the widget
```

In particular, I re-initialized it with parameters, e.g.:

```
$('#MySelect').multiselect({selectedList: 4, header: false});
```

If anybody has read this far down and is still having troubles, give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

well this plugin works fine but I have a pb with destroy and filter: my combo data are loaded with ajax. So, when I refresh the data with ajax call, I call destroy to refresh the plugin:

```
myCombo.multiselect('destroy');
myCombo.multiselect().multiselectfilter();
```

It works for the first call: empty combo, ajax call to load data, call the functions above.
But if I refresh the combo data and call again the above functions, the filter disappeared?
Someone experienced this pb before and found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

For [wenzhixin MultiSelect](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/):

```
var i = jQuery('input');
i.data('multipleSelect').$parent.remove();
i.removeData('multipleSelect');
i.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used it in this way :

```
$("#<%= cmbInBayiID.ClientID %>").multiselect().trigger('reset');
```

It worked.

Comment: Using scriplets is bad, and you should feel bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function setMultiSelect(idElement, paramVal){
        eval("$('#"+idElement+"').multiselect('uncheckAll')");
        $.each($('input[name="multiselect_'+idElement+'"]'), function(k,i) {    
            if(paramVal.indexOf(this.value)!=-1){
                this.checked = true; 
            }
        }); 
         eval("$('#"+idElement+"').multiselect('update')");
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what this does?

Answer (score 0):

```
var valArr = ["1", "2"],
         i = 0,
      size = valArr.length,
  $options = $('#MySelect option');

for (i; i < size; i++) {
  $options.filter('[value="' + valArr[i] + '"]').prop('selected', true);
}

$('#MySelect').multiselect('reload');
```

1.valArr is values of select Options
2.for loop to set selected to matched option based on valArr
 
3.our changes is only in hidden select element
 
4.to change in multiselect generated elements we need to reload
5.every pluggin may have different name to reload eg:update,refresh

Comment: Do not just post code as an aswer. Explain it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced the same issue but finally, I resolved. Please use `$(selecter).multiselect("refresh");` instead of `$(selecter).multiselect("reload")`;

Answer (score 0):

For this first load the option in drop down and then apply multiselect on that
please refer the below code

```
 for (let mm = 0; mm < msg.d.length; mm++) {
                        $('#ddl_product_lst').append(new Option(msg.d[mm].Text, msg.d[mm].Value));
                    }
                    $('#ddl_product_lst').multiSelect({
                        noneText: '--Select Product--',
                        minWidth: 100

                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
$("#MySelect").multiselect("clearSelection");
```

Option 2:

```
$("#MySelect option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
$("#MySelect").multiselect('refresh');
```